# OpenGL, extract "sprites" from .pzx and .mpl in GLS_BINARY_LSB_FIRST format

Tags: opengl, sprite, irix

I'm seeking help in extracting sprites from an old file type.

The sprites are stored in this >>GLS_BINARY_LSB_FIRST<< format in .pzx files, alongside with some other .mpl files.

They seem to be in some kind of OpenGL format, although I did not find any information about  their structure.

The only system capable of "handling" these files is an old IRIX64, which I tried in an emulator but didn't worked.

My Question is if it's possible to extract the data from them to possibly OpenGL Textures that I could then write to sprites?

Best regards!

I uploaded a sample 001.mpl and 001.pzx here:
[Link](https://workupload.com/archive/zvyfmXbB)

Comment: No, OpenGL does not define any such formats, GLS is [something different](https://nixdoc.net/man-pages/IRIX/man3/glsintro.3.html)

Comment: @derhass, well it says it right there "OpenGL Stream Codec", so I assumed it would be OpenGL... What other could it be then?

Comment: It is an obscure format from SGI days, which is not part of OpenGL in any way. You will need to dig up some old GLS spec to decode this format (the binary encoding is briefly mentioned in the manpage I linked, but not the exact opcodes and format specifics) - which _then_ will give you a prehistoric GL command stream.